# magento 2 how to add tab in custom module

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 how to create a tab in the admin custom menu, under the tabs I need to display my UI component grid data on how to achieve it. I need to create two tabs under the custom admin menu. Please give any suggestions.

Comment: i need tab in custom page admin end

Comment: Do you need a custom tab on the admin edit page?

Comment: try this `https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197985/magento-2-adding-tab-in-custom-module-edit-section`